# Emulate middle mouse button with AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to write a simple script (one-liner?) to map the left shift + right mouse button to the middle mouse button (I don't actually have a middle mouse button, as it is a trackpad).

I have tried variations of this:

```
#(LShift & RButton)::MButton
```

or

```
(LShift & RButton::MButton
```

or

```
LShift & RButton::MButton
```

always with the error `Error: Invalid Hotkey`.  I came here through the somewhat less specific question:
[Emulate middle mouse click on a two button mouse in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/326028/emulate-middle-mouse-click-on-a-two-button-mouse-in-windows-7)

Comment: You can use `<+RButton` to get rid of the error. However, the behavior I get on my machine is weird and I couldn't get what you want...

Comment: This seems to work for me!: `<+RButton::MButton`
Happy to accept it as an answer, but it is odd that it is not behaving well for you.

Comment: Odd indeed. I'll post it as an answer anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<+RButton::MButton` to get what you want.

I'm not sure why your last line didn't work though. But `<+` is a shortcut for left shift, and apparently Autohotkey prefers it.